# Poset property that an element has a unique maximal element above it

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

**Definition:**

- Consider a partially ordered set $(\mathcal X,\leq)$ with a top element $\top$.
- Call an element **proper** when it is not equal to $\top$.  If $X'\leq X$ then say that $X$ is **above** $X'$.
- Call a subset $\mathcal X'\subseteq\mathcal X$ **up-directed** when every $X,X'\in\mathcal X'$ has an upper bound in $\mathcal X'$.

Now for something less familiar:

**Definition:**
Call $C\in\mathcal X$ **cotopen** when $\{X\in\mathcal X \mid C\leq X<\top\}$ is up-directed.

In words: $C$ is cotopen when the set of proper elements above $C$ is directed.

In the special case that $\mathcal X$ is finite, it is easy to see that $C$ being cotopen is equivalent to $C$ being beneath a (unique) greatest proper element.  That is, there exists some unique maximal $C\leq M<\top$.

**Question:** Has cotopenness been defined and studied, either for its own sake in order theory or arising as a useful property in ordered structures, and if so can anyone provide references?

Thank you.